# Compare two tables in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

For example I do have two DataFrames in Pandas:

First like:

```
id brand model

1 BMW E30
7 Mercedes W222
5 BMW E46
3 Mercedes W201
```

Second one like:

```
id mpg weight

1 15 5000
3 12 4000
7 10 3000
5 20 4500
```

So I need to put second columns (with mpg and weight) into first dataframe with checking by ID:

```
id brand model mpg weight
1 BMW E30 15 5000
7 Mercedes W222 10 3000
5 BMW E46 20 4500
3 Mercedes W201 12 4000
```

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: simple merge `df1.merge(df2,how='left')`

Answer (score 1):

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['id'])
```